# Java and .Net interoperability

Tags: java, .net, iis

I'm attempting to use the WebI ReportEngine SDK (AKA RENET) to change the Universe that is assigned to a WebIntelligence (WebI) rpeort.

Much research led me to the changeDataSource() method (exposed by the Java version of the SDK, AKA REBean).  Unfortunately, the changeDataSource() method isn’t available in the .Net version of the WebI ReportEngine SDK (AKA RENET).  In fact, there doesn't appear to be a way to do this simple task in the .Net version of the SDK.

My plan is to write a simple Java/JSP XmlWebService with a single method that wraps the REBean's changeDataSource() method, then reference the WebService in my .Net application.

Unfortunately, I don't have a lot of experience with the requirements of a Java/JSP XmlWebService.  My assumption is that I need a dedicated box to run Tomcat as not to interfere with IIS.  What software 'stack' do I need to get this working?

Is there a better alternative?

Any thoughts are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a dedicated box. Just configure tomcat to run on a different port than IIS.

An alternative is to use something lower-level than Web Services.

- write a simple Java application that listens on a ServerSocket. Simply write some data to this port from .Net end.
- write an even simpler Java application with command-line interface. Ideal if you need this method only rarely. Fire up JVM, do it, write result to stdout (or file), forget it. Read stdout on the .Net end.
- Use JNI (http://java.sys-con.com/node/45840)

Comment: I like the first option.  Do you know where I might look to find a bit of code?